# Using images as hyperlink in javascript for Windows 8 metro

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In my home.html I have:

```
<a href="/pages/page2/page2.html">Go to page2</a>
```

which is handled by home.js:

```
WinJS.Utilities.query("a").listen("click", linkClickEventHandler, false);
```

and linkClickEventHandler defined:

```
function linkClickEventHandler(eventInfo)
{
   eventInfo.preventDefault();
   var link = eventInfo.target;
   WinJS.Navigation.navigate(link.href);
}
```

As you can see, I am overriding the behaviour of `<a>` to use Page Control navigation instead of normal HTML navigation.

When clicking on "Go to page2" it successfully changes the Page Control from home.html to page2.html

Now what if instead of just text "Go to page2" I want to use an image inside the `<a>` tags:

```
<a href="/pages/page2/page2.html"><img src="page2.png" /></a>
```

This doesn't seem to work. I've gotten the image to load up and showing but when I click on it it seems to try to display the image in text format as the page control changes to some garbage text full of unknown (square) characters that start with 'PNG... PHOTOSHOP..." (I used photoshop to create the image)

I've also tried adding:

```
WinJS.Utilities.query("img").listen("click", linkClickEventHandler, false);
```

but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Replace `var link = eventInfo.target` with `var link = eventInfo.currentTarget;`. Did it help? )

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks raina. Would you mind explaining what the difference is? Does target refer to the img tag instead of the a tag or something?

Comment: @raina77ow Make that an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
var link = eventInfo.currentTarget;
```

... instead. See, there's a subtle yet important difference between `eventInfo.currentTarget` and `eventInfo.target` (quoting [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453015.aspx)):

> The `target` property returns the element that originally received an
>   event. However, the `currentTarget` property returns the element that
>   the event handlers are being processed for during the capturing and
>   bubbling phases.

The bug is caused by `eventInfo.target` being an Image element, and not a Link one. ) See, technically `click` event first occurs within that `<img src... />`; eventually it got to the outer `<a href="...">` element (so-called `bubbling`), but its original target (= eventInfo.target) is still the same! So your script actually navigates to the URL specified in `src` attribute of your image (taken as its `href` property value).

Comment: Ok, so because the function linkClickEventHandler is being called for the <a> tags then currentTarget is the <a> tag. but the event has been called for the <img> tag and thats why target is <img>?

Comment: @Arvin Exactly. ) See, that event handler has been assigned to `<a>` element, therefore it processes events when their _current_ target is at `<a>`.